# What does "hyperlink annotations" mean?

Tags: html

> A hyperlink can have one or more hyperlink annotations that modify the processing semantics of that hyperlink.

source:https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#hyperlink-annotation

How to add hyperlink annotations?

Comment: Hyperlink Annotation
The keyword may be specified on a and area elements; it annotates other hyperlinks created by the element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel